# How to get option value of select element

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to get the option value of a select element using Protractor. However, I'm not able to find the option element.

**HTML**

```
<select ng-options="opions.c as options.n for option in options" ng-model="model">
    <option value="0">Option 1</option>
    <option value="1">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

**Spec-file**

```
describe('testing select option', function() {
    it('', function() {
        ptor = protractor.getInstance();

        //This will not get the option required
        ptor.findElement(protractor.By.binding('model'));
    });
});
```

I cannot seem to find a way to grab the option value as I haven't found a function that I can use that doesn't give and exception or error message.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: No one in this thread answered the question posed by the op--not even the op in their answer!  *All* answers downvoted.

Comment: @7stud If you look at the answer posted by himself, you will know what he wants to know is actually different from the question he posted . He asks about how to get the selected value from the drop down while his answer is actually how to select one of the options from the drop down by clicking on it. He has no clue about what he wants.

Comment: I think stating that I did not know what I wanted is not helpful at all. If you aren't able to offer any kind of constructive answer to this thread then please do not answer or comment. This doesn't help the community only criticise it's members. I failed to state the select option value in the answer, however the code shows what was intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok again I have now been able to figure out how to grab the option element with protractor.

the example code below shows how to accomplish this.

```
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.css('select option:nth-child(value of the option you require IE: the number)')).click();
```

Answer (score 36):

I have had some problems getting dropdowns working well, and have spent some time today working it out (and therefore I'm sharing it here in case someone else finds it useful).

On earlier versions of Protractor there was a by.selectedOption, which effectively does the same thing as by.select, but returns only the selected item.  So, to get the text of the selected option above, you could have:

```
expect(element(by.selectedOption('model')).getText()).toEqual('Option 1');
```

I wrote a blog post if you want more detail, it also covers a helper function for selecting the option in the dropdown: http://technpol.wordpress.com/2013/12/01/protractor-and-dropdowns-validation/

Recent versions of protractor have removed this function, replacing it with:

```
expect(element(by.id('my_id')).element(by.css('option:checked')).getText();
```

Which is more flexible, as it can be applied to any of the finders, whereas selectedOption only worked with a model finder.

Comment: thanks for sharing your research information with us!

Comment: But how do you get the value of the 'value' property?  I tried getCssValue('value') but that did not work for me.

Comment: Thanks. What was an eye-opener for me was the `option:checked` selector. I had previously tried the `option:selected` to no avail, even though it returned the proper elements in my Chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

Try using xPath:

`ptor.findElement(protractor.By.xpath('//select/option[1]'));`

You can use the same technique to choose an option by value:

`protractor.By.xpath('//select/option[text()="Option 2"]'));`

I've needed to do this for setting up forms where inputs are visible based on selected dropdowns, e.g.:

```
makeFord = protractor.By.xpath('//select[@id="make"]/option[text()="Ford"]'));
modelMustang = protractor.By.xpath('//select[@id="model"]/option[text()="Mustang"]'));
makeFord.click();
modelMustang.click();
```

Comment: the issue with using xpath is that the paths may change as development proceeds, this makes tests brittle and prone to failure. using css can also have the same affect. Using id tags is the best solution as long as the frontend team understand that changes to these are not required as some front end developers don't like id tags or as PaulL recommends below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get *the value* of an option in a select:

**HTML**

```
<select ng-options="opions.c as options.n for option in options" ng-model="model">
    <option value="Africa">Option 1</option>
    <option value="Switzerland">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

**.spec file**

```
describe("Country <select>", function() {

  it("should have 'Africa' as the value of the first option", function() {

    browser.get('index.html');

    let all_options = element.all(
      by.options("opions.c as options.n for option in options") //use whatever string is assigned to the ng-options attribute in the html
    );

    let first_option = all_options.get(0);  //or all_options.first()
    let second_option = all_options.get(1); //or all_options.last()

    expect(
      first_option.getAttribute('value')
    ).toEqual("Africa");                           

  });

});
```

To get *the value* of a **selected option** (which can be an option programmatically selected with protractor by calling click() on an option):

```
    expect(
      element(    
        by.model('model') //'model' is the string assigned to the select's ng-model attribute                                
      ).element(                  
          by.css('option:checked') 
        ).getAttribute('value')
    ).toEqual('Swizerland');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help.

```
//check whether the selected value is equal to the expected value.
expect(element(by.model("model")).getAttribute('value')).toEqual("0");

//catch the selected value
element(by.model("model")).getAttribute('value').then(function (value) {
   console.log('selected value', value);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to enumerate the option tags you can try to use the `.all` method and you should access it by the parent first.

```
element(by.model('model')).all(by.tagName('option')).then(function(arr) {
        expect(arr.length).toEqual(2);
});
```

Have a look at the API reference for inspiration

http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.all

Edit: also follow the style guide which discourages usage of XPath 
http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide