# angular Protractor e2e tests and select value?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I'm having problems to get currently selected value of the select element. In some cases I can use:

```
element(by.css('#some-select')).$('[selected]').getText();
```

And it works just fine. But as I figured out it works only because selected attribute is present on option element. If I select option with javascript by setting select's value this way it's not possible to get element by selected attribute.

**What is the proper way to get selected option or it's text because I can't find answer anywhere.**

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so right now I feel stupid and a little enraged at the same time.

It turns out that there is a simple way to get the option that is selected by simply calling:

```
element(by.selectedOption('model-name'));
```

Documentation [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#protractorbyprototypeselectedoption)

I feel like this is a wrong way to do because instead of reusing element locator cache that I have defined (select element) I need to use new locator "selectedOption". It feels bad because naturally I would like to simply call something like `element(by.css('#some-select')).getSelected();`

**But maybe there is a way that I could not just find?**

Comment: it seems `by.selectedOption(` was removed from recent protractor version. See this other answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20308252/587407

Answer (score 0):

So I just ran into this, and I couldn't find any answer that I really liked..

## My Answer

First, I recommend changing the `ng-options` by adding `track by` statement.

for example:

```
<select ng-options="l.id as ('filters.languages.' + l.id | translate) for l in limitedLanguages track by l.id" ng-model="filterLanguage">
</select>
```

This will add the `id` on the option element so instead of getting

```
<select ng-options="l.id as ('filters.languages.' + l.id | translate) for l in languages" ng-model="filterLanguage" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
    <option value="0">All</option>
    <option value="1" selected="selected">English</option>
    <option value="2">Hebrew</option>
    <option value="3">Russian</option>
    <option value="4">Arabic</option>
    <option value="5">Other</option>
</select>
```

you get

```
<select ng-options="l.id as ('filters.languages.' + l.id | translate) for l in languages track by l.id" ng-model="filterLanguage" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched">
    <option value="all" selected="selected">All</option>
    <option value="english">English</option>
    <option value="hebrew">Hebrew</option>
    <option value="russian">Russian</option>
    <option value="arabic">Arabic</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>
```

note that without the `track by` the value is simply the index (0,1,..) and with the track by the value is more readable/meaningful (all,english,...)

then you can use `getAttribute` on value to get the value as mentioned in other answers.