# How to get selected option value in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, selectedvalue

How can I get currently selected option value of selectbox?

I have tried below code but it's not working.

```
element(by.css('#selectbox')).all(by.tagName('option')).then(function (options) {
    options.forEach(option => {
        if (option.getAttribute('selected')) {
            console.log('selected option', option);
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get option value of select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401812/how-to-get-option-value-of-select-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is "selected" and attribute or a class-value?

It would work as "get element, which is selected, then read out its value"

In code:

```
//if selected is an attribute
element(by.css('#selectbox option[selected]')).getAttribute('value').then(function(value){
    console.log('selected option is '+value);
})

//if selected is a class-attribute
element(by.css('#selectbox option.selected')).getAttribute('value').then(function(value){
    console.log('selected option is '+value);
})

//note, that "element(by.css())" === "$()", so this is the same as the first one
$('#selectbox option[selected]').getAttribute('value').then(function(value){
    console.log('selected option is '+value);
})
```

[Read more here about locators](http://www.protractortest.org/#/locators) and even more important [here about CSS-Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `.filter()` to filter out the selected option, or target it directly with a CSS selector:

```
element(by.css('#selectbox option[selected]'))
```

Note that there is an overall nicer way to deal/interact with the `select` in Protractor:

- [Select -> option abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28723419/771848)