# Protractor if, else does not work

Tags: javascript, angular, automation, protractor

I m trying to check a if condition and do a click if its true, but it returns me a error 'eachOperator.toEqual is not a function'

```
var selectDropdownbyNum = function (element, optionNum) {  
    var opt = element.all(by.tagName('option'));
    opt.each(function (eachOperator) {
        eachOperator.toEqual('-').then(function (subtract) {
            if (subtract) {
                eachOperator.click();
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/47630843/3085279

Comment: @TanDuong thanks but seems no luck with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you try it or?

```
var selectDropdownbyNum = function (element, optionNum) {  
    var opt = element.all(by.tagName('option'));
    opt.each(function (eachOperator) {
        eachOperator.getAttribute('value').then(function (value) {
            if (value === '-') {
                eachOperator.click();
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: It worked with some modifications, where I had to change the value="subtraction"

Comment: Nice to help you :)