# Check if select field is selected in Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I am writing a test which takes into consideration whether a select has been pre-populated.

```
it('should select field if it was not selected', function() {
  var usersField = element(by.id('users'));

  usersField.getAttribute('value').then(function(value) {
    console.log('value = ', value);

    if(!value) {
      //select first option if not pre-populated
      usersField.all(by.tagName('option')).get(0).click();
    }
  });
});
```

I have tried usersField.getText() but that just lists all the options from the dropdown so it doesn't help. My console log returns `? object:null ?` for the value. Why is that? How can I simply check the value of the selected option if it's there and if not, select the first option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get selected option value in protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47588304/how-to-get-selected-option-value-in-protractor)

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure the element actually has a `value` attribute? maybe it doesn't.
And also, have you tried with `isSelected()` method?

```
var foo = element(by.id('foo'));
expect(foo.isSelected()).toBe(false);
```